# Codeblocks: needing compiled src in another project

Tags: c++, codeblocks

how can I add *.h file with it's own compiled *.o file to my project, so I can use it's functions etc. I'm using codeblocks and trying to set paths for compiler & linker but it still can't recognize the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you have a .h file and .o file all ready from another project, and wish to add them to your current project, but want to keep the .o definitions hidden from the external users of your current project.

Add your .o file to your current project, and make sure it physically exist in your linker path.  Then add the .h file to this project, and make sure it exists alongside your sources (not inside the include folder), and make sure it exists inside your compiler path.

Right-click the .o file and click on Properties.  Then navigate to the Build tab, and check off 'Link file'.

Right-click your current project, and click on Build options.  Then in the general build configuration, add -lNAMEOFOBJECTFILE.o to your linker options.

Now... this is not a typical pattern in C++ and I advise you look into creating a shared library that has the 'hidden' code you wish to use, and link your final binary against a .dll/.so.   Also, if the .o file uses any external dependencies, then this will not work for you, so the suggested route I recommend, is building a shared library file, then linking against that.  When you release your code, you can always omit include .h files that have symbols that you want to keep hidden in your final API.

Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I see what you want.  Take the .o file from the previous project, then add them to the project you want to use them in, including the header files that have the definitions, but place these header files along side your source folder, and not inside your include folder.  Then for the .o file, right-click->Properties->Build and only check Link file. Ill modify my answer to give more detail.

Comment: I updated my answer.  You will need to make sure the .o file is in a directory where the linker can see it, then just add -LNAMEOFOBJECT.o to your projects linker options for each build configuration you are using.  Also, you can omit the .h file from your include folder when ready to release the code.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thank you

Comment: I'm happy I could help.  Codeblocks is a great IDE for C++, and I am happy to see people using it. :D